# Posting an http request from whithin AWS- lambda function console, using the Alexa as the input

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

**Alexa skill lambda Function trying to send an http request to localhost port 8000**

I've been stuck on this for a while and, no matter what I try the Alexa always says the error message: 'there is a problem with the requested skill's response.

The request format I used is standard for node js but for some reason, it does not work within the AWS lambda function console.

Could really use some help (I'm not really experienced at coding in node or js, I've really only done python before so sorry if I made a dumb error)

Thanks!

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');



const APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.4201f25c-5da7-4668-89ef-321896522bb8';

const SKILL_NAME = 'make request';
const INTRO = "we are going to try to make an H T M L request ";
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'sorry I just suck at getting data';
const GETTING_DATA = ' sorry I am dumb';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'i am sad';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';


const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit(':ask',INTRO);
    },

    'send_request': function () {
        const http = require("http");
        const PORT = 8000;

        const requestHandler = (req, res) => {
            res.write("trying to send a message")
            res.end("Hello from AWS Cloud9!")`enter code here`
        }

        const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

        server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error occurred", err) ;
            }

        })
        this.emit(':tell', `Server is listening on ${PORT}`);

    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        const speechOutput = HELP_MESSAGE;
        const reprompt = HELP_REPROMPT;

        this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Comment: There are at least a couple of things going on here, not the least of which is that it doesn't make sense to try to create a web server within the Lambda container and try to connect to it.  If you want to make a request to get content from a web server, then do that.  But don't try to put the server here.  Put it outside, get it working, then connect to it.  You have Internet access from your Lambda function.  Also, read your Lambda logs, in Cloudwatch.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with Node.js you can also write your code in Python for your lambda function. (Although, I believe you already know that). I'm unable to figure out, what you're trying to do here. Could you please elaborate your problem.